# Homophily across two attributes with nodematch in R package ergm

Tags: r, social-networking

We would greatly appreciate your help. We are working with network data in the `ergm` package in R and were wondering: is it possible to look at homophily effects with `nodematch` across two attributes?

An example might perhaps best illustrate our question. Say we had data on which languages participants speak: two columns with 'language1' and 'language2'. We would be interested to see if participants are more likely to form ties with someone who speaks the same language. It does not matter to us whether that language is 'language1' or 'language2', e.g. people who speak German as 'language1' or 'language2' being more likely to form ties with other people who speak German as either 'language1' or 'language2'. Would you perhaps know of some way to look at this kind of homophily effect?

It seems to be possible to examine homophily effects on both attributes together, as in the example I read [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42810583/r-ergm-specifying-nodematch-effect-on-two-attributes), and in the code I tried below. But is it also possible to examine homophily effects across attributes in some way, either with the `ergm` package or another package? Would you perhaps have any ideas on how we could approach this? That would be absolutely great. Thank you so much in advance for your help!

```
library(statnet)
data(sampson)
samplike%v%'language1' <- c('English', 'English', 'German', 'Italian', 'English', 'German', 'Italian', 'French', 'English', 'English', 'English', 'German', 'Italian', 'English', 'German', 'French', 'German', 'English')
samplike%v%'language2' <- c('German', NA, 'English', 'English', NA, NA, 'English', 'Italian', NA, 'German', NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 'English', 'Italian', NA)
m1 <- ergm(samplike ~ edges + nodematch(c('language1', 'language2'), diff = TRUE))
summary(m1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The statistic you want is one that counts the number of edges between nodes that match on at least one of two or more attributes. With the terms currently implemented, there is no great way to compute it, but it's not impossible.

## `edgecov`

If you can construct a 0-1 *n* by *n* matrix indicating whether two individuals have at least one language in common, you can use it in `edgecov`. This is probably the simplest way to do it, though of course not very memory-efficient. One way to do that is using `outer`. E.g.,

```r
l <- list(c('English','German'), c('Enlgish'), c('German', 'English'), ...
covmat <- outer(l, l, FUN=Vectorize(function(x,y) length(intersect(x,y))>0))
```

## `nodemix`

This approach is more memory-efficient but more tedious to set up.

1. Construct a vertex attribute containing a list (say, sorted and comma-separated) of the languages that actor speaks, e.g,. `c("English,German", "English", "English,German", "English,Italian", ...)`.
2. Use `nodemix` or `mm` term on this attribute. This will produce a rather large mixing matrix.
3. Identify which cells in that matrix correspond to counts of relations with at least one language in common.
4. Use the `levels2` argument to only count those cells.
5. Either use the grouping functionality in `nodemix` (see `ergmTerm?nodemix`) or the `Sum` term operator to sum up the cells.